# CodeDomProvider still uses TempFiles when using GenerateInMemory

Tags: c#, codedom

So im running a multi-threaded operation that often runs the exact same source to assemble/compile at the exact same time causing it to return exceptions stating it could not access a file in local app data. (Usually a .err or .out file) yet in CompilerParameters I told it to `GenerateInMemory`.

Why it is storing temporary files and how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

CodeDom will always generate temp files. The GenerateInMemory option only relates to whether the output dll is saved to disk.

You can set the TempFiles property of CompilerParameters to use a safe path of your choosing, but usually the temp files generated have unique random file names so I’m not sure what conflict you’re running into.

Comment: Im using a caching system where I essentially Cache the "Compiled"/"Assembly" and the "Type" (Method) in a Concurrent Dictionary using a value tuple to be able to hold both values. Where key = a assigned string to reference and value = the tuple of the 2 items. This allows me to not actually have to compile the same thing every time. Im assuming since im referencing the same actual objects those objects also reference the same file resulting in often collisions in HDD I/O

Comment: Not sure why if it’s using random file names. Unless the “random” component is actually some kind of hash of the content.